It is possible to Subtract pairs of values from a DataSet and assign these results to another Dataset?
I need to graph, in the real model time, the results of subtracting the [i+1] and [i] values over the values ​​in a data set. (Subtraction=[i+1] - [i]).
I prepared an event Timeout triggered, that  Occur one 1 year,   steps are:
1.- A for loop will be executed only if there are values different than 0, on the i and the i+1 indexes.
2.-The subtraction operation will be performed and the result, with the index, is passed to the empty dataset,  that will be used to plot these new values.
3.-The index and the result of the subtraction will be passed to the destination Dataset ( that will be graphed.) The index will increase itself, wainting for the next iteration.
4.- If there is missing some of the pairs values, that needs to be subtracted, the action will be to asign the same already substracted value with the index, later the index will increase itself also.
The events´ body:

int index =0;
double resultado =0;
// Simulación: llenar la lista con valores del stock al cambiar de año


  for (int i = 0; i < TFGDS.size(); i++) {
      if (i < TFGDS.size() - 1 && TFGDS.getY(i) != 0.0 && TFGDS.getY(i + 1) != 0.0) {

                resultado = TFGDS.getY(i+1)-TFGDS.getY(i); // Realizando la resta
                      TFGValorAnual.add(index, resultado);  // Asignando valores
                index++; // Aumentando el valor para la proxima asignacion
              
                 }else{
                     TFGValorAnual.add(index, resultado); // asignando el valor anterior
                     index++; // Aumentando el valor para la proxima asignacion
                 }
  };


The result: the event can assign only 2 indexes with values as zero, to the destination dataset, while the origin dataset is growing .
I can't figure it out where the mistake is.

Hey, suggest you use traceln(...) to understand in detail what is happening in your code. Some i stuff looks fishy. I think you have a wrong understanding of how the code really works (which is where traceln(...) can be very helpful). See https://anylogic.help/advanced/functions/traceln.html#traceln

I changed the event trigger type and adjusted it to start with a restart method. The event can now perform the first three operations but stops with the error "There is no data item with this index: 4," indicating insufficient values for the next operation.
It appears the event is running faster than the dataset is being populated.
Is there a way to verify that the dataset has the correct number of values before executing the event? The event subtracts values from the current and next positions in the dataset, so the next value must always be present for the event to continue.

Pls understand indeces and your dataset size. You are trying to access a value at i+1 when your dataset only has i entries. Hence the error. Use traceln and you will understand what is truly happening. Ideally, build a small toy model with known dataset values

I stopped using for loop. Instead the event will occur every 2 years. This will make my new dataset the middle size as the original one. But this will work for plot in real time.
I prepared a variable (i) that will be increased every time change. This will be the dataset guide point to make the subtraction.
The subtraction formula needs to be

resultado = TFGDS.getY(i-1)-TFGDS.getY(i-2);

for being sure the event is using the dataset existing values, as the event is occuring every 2 years.
Thank you all for making my brain more creative.
